# CKEditor in Modal Bootstrap

Tags: ckeditor, bootstrap-modal

I have this code in admin page

```
<div class="control-group">                     
<label class="control-label" for="isi">Keterangan Alur</label>
<div class="controls">
  <textarea class="span6" name="editalur<?php echo $daftar->ALUR_ID; ?>" id="editalur<?php echo $daftar->ALUR_ID; ?>" value="<?php echo $daftar->ALUR_ID; ?>"></textarea>
  <?php 
    echo "<script>";
    echo "CKEDITOR.replace( 'editalur".$daftar->ALUR_ID."' );";
    echo "</script>";
  ?>
</div> <!-- /controls -->       
<label class="control-label"></label>
```

The code is inside bootstrap modal tag. My goal is make a modal for every button i have in admin page. But it shows all the ckeditor like this.

[image]

I have no idea to make this works. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I get this works by changing the way i load ckeditor. I just read its documentation and they provide a way to load ckeditor by adding class "ckeditor" in textarea tag